# Push vented gas cap vs standard gas cap

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, fuel-cap

I have a 2008 Toyota RAV4 and am replacing the gas cap.  At AutoZone, I can choose from a standard cap or a vented fuel cap:

- AutoZone 6817A is a standard gas cap: https://www.autozone.com/fuel-delivery/fuel-cap/p/duralast-fuel-cap-6817a/848451_0_0
- AutoZone 6819A has a push vent: https://www.autozone.com/fuel-delivery/fuel-cap/p/duralast-fuel-cap-6819a/848447_0_0

What is the benefit of the push vent, and is it worth the extra money?

Comment: The idea is to equalise the pressure before removing the cap. In both cases, open the cap gradually. I've never had one, and have never thought "If only I could equalise the pressure, it would save me 1 second each time I fill up." But if you have trouble unscrewing the cap against the pressure, it might be worth it.